# How do you convert from ArrayBuffer to byte array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#

How do you convert from ArrayBuffer to byte array in javascript? 
I get the data of an image in ArrayBuffer format from angular. I want to convert the arraybuffer data to []byte so it matches the backend model of the object.